# Changing data types of a software module

Tags: c, replace, sed

I am trying to componentise a software, where I need to change the datatypes. like replace all `int` into `xint_t`. To do this to all the files in the module folder, I tried doing this

```
find ./*.c | sed -i 's/\<int\>/xint_t/'
```

But when I do this , i am not getting the result what I want.

Ex: `foo(int a,int b)` and `foo(int a, int b)`
 It misses the cases where it finds int as the second argument. What is the reason for this behaviour and How do i write a **sed** command to overcome this problem

And yes I need to take care of pointers too. like cases `int* a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find . -type f -name "*.c" -exec sed -i.bak 's/\bint\b/xint_t/g' {} \;
```

This would change `int` to `xint_t` in all `*.c` files and keep copies of the original `.c` files as `.bak`.

Comment: `\b` denotes word boundary.

Comment: Thanks, Will it take care of pointers too? and what is i.bak?

Comment: `-i` is in-place editing.  Saying `-i.bak` would make sed keep backups of original files.  If you don't need backups, say `-i` instead.

Comment: Yes, `\b` would take care of pointers too.  Moreover, executing it multiple times wouldn't hurt either as the word boundary wouldn't match `uint` or such.  Rejoice!

Comment: i have unsigned char and char data types, using the same above, for these types too. ofc unsigned char first. Guess it goes thro successfully. .   :) with out any side effects.  :)

Comment: and wat does {} \; for ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the "-i.bak" means to save the result as filename.bak for filename.c as input file. Right?

Comment: @lulyon No, it'd save the original as `filename.c.bak`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
find ./ -name "*.c" | xargs sed -i "s/\<int\>/xint_t/g"
```